# In Internet Explorer 10 Metro, how do you change the home page?

Tags: windows-8-preview, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10

There appear to be two copies of Internet Explorer in Windows 8; the Metro version, and the normal version. The Internet Options settings do not appear to apply to the Metro version of IE; and the Metro IE does not appear to have a way to configure it.

Can anyone tell me how to get to the options for the Metro version of IE, specifically to change the home page?

Comment: Have you tried clicking the "Settings" charm while you have the Metro IE open?

Comment: @techie007 - there is no homepage setting in the settings charm for metro ie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the internet explorer **on the desktop**. Go to internet options, General (first) tab.
There you can set a homepage. This will be used when ie is started from the metro UI.

Comment: It's nice to see they fixed that in later RCs. In the original, the Metro version did not use the homepage option from the Desktop version.

Answer (score 3):

There is no home button or hotkey for Metro IE10. I recommend you use IE10 through the desktop if you want homepage functionality. If you want to know where the settings menu is on Metro IE10, just use (Win + i).

Comment: So Metro IE operates on a 'always remember the previously opened tabs' paradigm?

Comment: Sure does. I've looked through all of Internet Explorers registry and I don't think you have access to Metro apps. Talk about disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

the only way to sort of create a homepage for the metro page is to open IE. Then type the site you want to be your homepage in the address bar below, when the page is displayed click the pin button to the right.  This will bring a box up - click pin to start.  This will pin that page to your IE button.  Next time you open IE it will refresh to the page that you pinned to it.  This is the closet you will get to a homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that you have already launched the default Metro IE 10.

Right click in the IE 10 interface, and you should see control icons at the bottom of the screen.

Select the Wrench, then 'View on the Desktop'. (If no bar appears try WinKey +z)

The difference is that now you will see the traditional Internet Explorer and crucially, that cog at the top where you can make your internet options.

[More on Windows 8 IE 10.](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-ie10.htm)

Comment: However, that answer explicitly switches to the non-metro IE. The question was about the IE10 Metro application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your desktop IE in a traditional manner through internet options to set a homepage that will open a correlate with IE 10/Metro.

Answer (score 0):

I have made my own page open in both the Metro and the Desktop Internet Explorers with Windows 8 using a Registry Edit.

Simply substitute your page for MyHome.HTM

Cheers, PW.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Local Page"="D:\\Internet\\MyHome.HTM"
"Start Page"="file:///D:/Internet/MYHOME.HTM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag to your site...Let them do it them self.

Reference:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/web-sites-and-a-plug-in-free-web)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question it would be beneficial to copy the pertinent information into your answer and link to the site as a source.  Links are subject to deletion and change and your answer may become invalid at some random time in the future.