# How to set an home page for Modern UI IE10?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Internet Explorer 10 Metro, how do you change the home page?](https://superuser.com/questions/396943/in-internet-explorer-10-metro-how-do-you-change-the-home-page)

How I can set an home page to Modern UI IE10 in Windows 8?

It appears to show the latest open tabs, or a blank one.

I don't want neither, the first for a privacy issue, the second because I want my home page, instead of the about:blank.

Comment: You would not need to edit any registry settings. You can simply open IE in Desktop mode and click on Tools -> Internet Options -> General and set your home page. IE would open this page even on opening it as a Modern UI.

Comment: @AbhishekGirish does not work, there is no home page anymore, there is what is called a start page which can have more than one link. Horrid to navigate unless you have a touchscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to edit the registry - specifically:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Local Page"="www.google.co.nz"
"Start Page"="http://www.google.co.nz/"
```

Comment: It worked! My local page was set to c:\windows\system32\blank.html