# Where is the 'Home' button in internet explorer for windows 8

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Internet Explorer 10 Metro, how do you change the home page?](https://superuser.com/questions/396943/in-internet-explorer-10-metro-how-do-you-change-the-home-page)

I set my homepage in desktop IE in windows 8. Went back into 'metro', opened internet explorer and it doesn't go to the homepage, and I see no homepage button.

Comment: There isn't one. For what it's worth, my IE 'app' does open the same page as the home page I have set on the desktop version of IE.

Answer (score 0):

In IE10, click on the wrench icon and choose "View on the desktop."  You will see the IE9 style window complete with home button.